# How can I replace iterative execution of stored procedure with anything in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, while-loop

There is a scenario wherein a SP is executed inside a WHILE loop. I want a solution which can prevent iterative execution of SP but at the same time getting exact same result.
Below code snippet could be an example. Consider SP uspMyProc is updating tables based on the parameter it gets.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      id INT IDENTITY
    , Value INT
    )
DECLARE @counter INT = 1
  , @maxcount INT
  , @value INT
INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 11 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 23 ),
        ( 2 )

SELECT  @maxcount = COUNT(*)
FROM    @table

WHILE @counter <= @maxcount
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @value = Value
        FROM    @table
        WHERE   id = @counter

        EXECUTE uspMyProc @id = @value

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END
```

Comment: can you show the code of `uspMyProc`? If it's possible to convert it to accept a table of values instead of a single value, then the whole operation can be set based and the iteration can be eliminated.

Comment: uspMyProc has approx 2000 lines of code, so its not possible to show it here. But it can be considered for the example that it has quite complex code, which ultimately is updating tables.

Comment: Yes, as Zohar Peled said, this coluld be done in set based manner in the sp itself. You need to handle list of parameters in your sp to handle.

Comment: You can't solve it purely from the "calling" side. You have to change the stored procedure itself.